# Ruby regexp /(\/.*?(?=\/|$)){2}/

Tags: ruby, regex

My regexp behaves just like I want it to on http://regexr.com, but *not* like I want it in irb.

I'm trying to make a regular expression that will match the following:

```
A forward slash, 
then 2 * any number of random characters (i.e. `.*`), 
  up to but not including another / 
  OR the end of the string (whichever comes first)
```

I'm sorry as that was probably unclear, but it's my best attempt at an English translation.

Here's my current attempt and hopefully that will give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
/(\/.*?(?=\/|$)){2}/
```

The usage scenario is I want to be able to take a path like `/foo/bar/baz/bin/bash` and shorten it to the level I'm at in the filesystem, in this case the second level (`/foo/bar`). I'm trying to do this using the command `path.scan(-regex-).shift`.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`/(?:\/[^\/]+){1,2}\z/`](http://rubular.com/r/VMA1YteYAk)?

Comment: So, what's wrong with the regex you've got?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Shouldn't it be `^(?:\/[^\/]+){1,2}` if he wants to get the beginning?

Comment: Usage would be Find `/((?:\/.*?(?=\/|$)){2}).*/` Replace `$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The usage scenario is I want to be able to take a path like /foo/bar/baz/bin/bash and shorten it to the level I'm at in the filesystem, in this case the second level (/foo/bar)*

Ruby already has a class for handling paths, [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). You can use [Pathname#relative_path_from](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-relative_path_from) to do what you want.

```
require 'pathname'

path = Pathname.new("/foo/bar/baz/bin/bash")

# Normally you'd use Pathname.getwd
cwd  = Pathname.new("/foo/bar")

# baz/bin/bash
puts path.relative_path_from(cwd)
```

---

Regexes just invite problems, like assuming the path separator is `/`, not honoring escapes, and not dealing with extra `/`. For example, `"//foo/bar//b\\/az/bin/bash"`. `//` is particularly common in code which joins together directories using `paths.join("/")` or `"#{dir}/#{file}`.

For completeness, the general way you match a single piece of a path is this.

```
%r{^(/[^/]+)}
```

That's the beginning of the string, a `/`, then 1 or more characters which are not `/`. Using `[^/]+` means you don't have to try and match an optional `/` or end of string, a very useful technique. Using `%r{}` means less [leaning toothpicks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

But this is only applicable to a canonicalized path. It will fail on `//foo//b\\/ar/`. You can try to fix up the regex to deal with that, or do your own canonicalization, but just use Pathname.